# Proving if a set is True or False: (A x B) $\cup$ (C x D) = (A $\cup$ C) x (B $\cup$ D)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

As the title suggests I'm trying to determine if the following example is true or false. AND if it is false, to provide a counter example.

This is the example:

**(A x B) $\cup$ (C x D) = (A $\cup$ C) x (B $\cup$ D)**

*Now here is what I have attempted:*

For the L.H.S. **(A x B) $\cup$ (C x D)**

(x,y) $\in$ (A x B) OR (x,y) $\in$ (C x D) $\Leftarrow\Rightarrow$ x $\in$ A OR y $\in$ B OR x $\in$ C OR y $\in$ D

For the R.H.S. **(A $\cup$ C) x (B $\cup$ D)**

x $\in$ (A $\cup$ C) OR y $\in$ (B $\cup$ D) $\Leftarrow\Rightarrow$ (x,y) $\in$(A  $\cup$ C) x (B $\cup$ D)

To be honest I'm not really sure if what I have done is even correct. *Given my working I guess it would be a FALSE statement?*

*But a counter example?* I just need the expertise on this forum to help me fill a few gaps.

Thanks so much!

EDIT: It is slightly different from the linked solution as they asked
$(A \times B) \cup (C \times D) = (A \cup B) \times (C \cup D)$

And I asked

(A x B) $\cup$ (C x D) = (A $\cup$ C) x (B $\cup$ D)

I realise that's not much of a difference but just thought for peoples future reference.

Comment: "Proving" is not the same as "determining". You only prove true things. It makes no sense to ask to prove if something is true or false.

Comment: Regarding your edit: That's a typo in the linked post. If you look at its content you see that it indeed answers your question.

Comment: My error! This forum is such a wealth of information, I really appreciate it! I'll search more diligently next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your answer.

$(x,y) \in (A \times B) \cup (C \times D) \implies (x,y) \in (A \times B)\ or \ (x,y) \in (C \times D) \implies (x \in A\ and\ y \in B)\ or\ (x \in C\ and\ y \in D)$

On the other hand,

$(x,y) \in (A \cup C) \times (B \times D) \implies (x \in A\ or\ x \in C)\ and\ (y \in B\ or\ y \in D)$.

Now we use the splitting properties of the $and$ and the $or$ operators. We replace $and$ by $\cdot$ ,and $or$ by $+$. Now, let us use the following boolean variables:

$W := x \in A$

$X := y \in B$

$Y := x \in C$

$Z := y \in D$

Then the above statements are rewritten respectively as:

$$
WX+YZ=(WX+Y)(WX+Z)=(W+Y)(X+Y)(W+Z)(X+Z)
$$

and

$$
(W+X)(Y+Z)
$$

As we see, $(W+Y)(X+Y)(W+Z)(X+Z)=(W+X)(Y+Z)$ is clearly not true all the time. So we have a good reason to assume that the statement above is false.

I decided to construct a counter example, in case you needed one: $A=\{1,2\}$,$B=\{1,4\}$,$C=\{3,7\}$,$D=\{1,3\}$. Not only is $(A \times B) \cup (C \times D) \neq (A \cup C) \times (B \times D)$, in fact their cardinalities are 8 and 12 respectively,  which are also not equal.

That brings me to the cardinalities of the  sets $(A \times B) \cup (C \times D)$ and $(A \cup C) \times (B \times D)$. If we let $a=|A|,b=|B|,c=|C|,d=|D|$, then the cardinality of the first set is less than or equal to $ab+cd$, while the cardinality of the second set is less than or equal to $(a+b)(c+d) > ab+cd$. If we find a set such that the cardinality of the second set is exactly $(a+b)(c+d)$, then we have a counterexample. My counterexample does not show this, but you can take it as an exercise and construct your own counterexample. I hope I have given you a different flavor of set theory through predicate calculus,and not merely confused you. Now you can attack any set theoretic problem using this cardinality bound method, or through direct predicate calculus.

Comment: Thank you! As the admin has pointed out I missed the question somehow in my search. Apologies for that